# Google in-app non-renewing subscription

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-services

Does google in-app purchase provide non-renewing subscription? Or do I have to simulate that using managed in-app products? I am following the language of the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html) which distinguishes managed in-app goods vs subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this post which indicates the answer is as you are already lead. 
[Does android playstore support non-renewing subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399551/does-android-playstore-support-non-renewing-subscription)

You would have to enforce your own expiration logic for a managed in-app good that specifies a duration.