# Does android playstore support non-renewing subscription?

Tags: android

My Question is can we provide the feature of non-renewing subscription in our android app??
so the user will be notified through mail that his/her subscription has been expired so he will resubscribe it manually as IOS does.

Comment: No, you need to use an normal inapp purchase and handle the duration yourself.

Comment: did you get the solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it does. see description from Android official doc:

> You can create a product list of digital goods that are associated
>   with  your application, including items for one-time purchase and
>   recurring  subscriptions. For each item, you can define information
>   such as the  item’s unique product ID (also called its SKU), product
>   type, pricing,  description, and how Google Play should handle and
>   track purchases for  that product.

It means there are two types:

Standard in-app products (one-time billing)

Subscriptions, (recurring, automated billing)

See detail doc here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html

Hopefully, it could help you.

Comment: yes but i have already read that doc, all i want to know is for this Subscriptions, (recurring, automated billing) is it possible that the subscription will not renew by it self istead of that it will notify the user that your subcription has been expired so the user will renew by him/herself manually.

Comment: From my understanding, and the experience in our product. We just put a one-purchase item for particular period such as 1 month. Yes, you have to build own billing logic to handle that. After one month, your app is responsible to notify user to purchase to extend the period in your billing system. Or, you want to build similar function without own billing system.

Comment: which product is suitable for this? products or subscription or rewarded products

Comment: I'm sorry but this answer doesn't really answer the question. You need to use "managed in-app" product for Android, it doesn't have the exact same thing as Apple.